# Sorting a nested list using lambda

Tags: python

Given a nested list representing gradebooks of different courses:

```py
gradebooks = [[['Troy', 92], ['Alice', 95]], [['James', 89], ['Charles', 100], ['Bryn', 59]]]
```

- Using the builtin `sorted()` function, write code to sort courses by course mean. The expected output is

```py
[[['James', 89], ['Charles', 100], ['Bryn', 59]], [['Troy', 92], ['Alice', 95]]]
```

- Using the builtin `sorted()` function, write code to sort students of each course by score in descending order. The expected output is

```py
[[['Alice', 95], ['Troy', 92]], [['Charles', 100], ['James', 89], ['Bryn', 59]]]
```

I'm having trouble with these questions, I tried to answer the first question using codes below but it doesnt work.

```py
sort1 = sorted(gradebooks, key=lambda x : sum(gradebooks[x]) / len(gradebooks[x]))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the reason your code does not work is:

```
sort1 = sorted(gradebooks, key=lambda x : sum(gradebooks[x]) / len(gradebooks[x]))
```

The parameter `key` of sorted function is a function that takes a list element as arguments. So `x` would be `[['Troy', 92], ['Alice', 95]]` or `[['Charles', 100], ['James', 89], ['Bryn', 59]]`. Therefore, `gradebooks[x]` will cause error:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list
```

---

For the first problem, your lambda function should be:

```
sort1 = sorted(gradebooks, key=lambda x: sum([grade for _, grade in x]) / len(x))
```

For the second problem, my thoughts are: overall it is a list comprehension, in the list comprehension, use `sorted` function to process each element.

```
sort2 = [sorted(course, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True) for course in gradebooks]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
# sort courses by course mean
sort1 = sorted(gradebooks, key=lambda s: sum(dict(s).values()) / len(s))

# sort students of each course by score in descending order. 
sort2 = list(map(lambda s: sorted(s, reverse=True, key=lambda y: y[1]),  gradebooks))

print(sort1)
print(sort2)
```

This prints:

```
[[['James', 89], ['Charles', 100], ['Bryn', 59]], [['Troy', 92], ['Alice', 95]]]
[[['Alice', 95], ['Troy', 92]], [['Charles', 100], ['James', 89], ['Bryn', 59]]]
```